# Why happens JMS exception in java?

Tags: java, exception, jmx, tibco

In messageProducer method send I receive JMSException during publish.
What are possible reason? What can happen during publish that produced JMSException?
Thanks.

Comment: Would you please show your code?

Comment: please post more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While publishing message on jms topic below exceptions are possible,

1. JMSSendException - If JMS send operation is failed.
2. JMSInvalidInputException - If input to the activity is not valid.
3. JMSMessageCreateException - If JMS message is not be created.
4. JMSSessionCreateException - If JMS session is not be created.

You can refer the doc 'TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks - Error Codes' for more details.

Thanks.